Odoo - cannot login with new user created from xml data records
I am writing a simple Odoo module for education purposes. I want to create two groups and one user for each group using the following xmls:
groups.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="module_category_educationcenter" model="ir.module.category">
            <field name="name">Education Center</field>
        </record>

        <record model="res.groups" id="educationcenter.group_admin">
            <field name="name">Admin</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_educationcenter"/>
        </record>

        <record model="res.groups" id="educationcenter.group_administrator">
            <field name="name">Administrator</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_educationcenter"/>
        </record>

    </data>

</odoo>

users.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record model="res.partner" id="educationcenter.partner_admin">
            <field name="name">Education Center Admin</field>
            <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_company"/>
            <field name="email">admin@example.com</field>
        </record>

         <record model="res.partner" id="educationcenter.partner_administrator">
            <field name="name">Education Center Administrator</field>
            <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_company"/>
            <field name="email">administrator@example.com</field>
        </record>

        <record id="admin" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">admin</field>
            <field name="login">admin</field>
            <field name="password">admin</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('educationcenter.group_admin'))]"/>
            <field name="partner_id" ref="educationcenter.partner_admin"/>
        </record>

        <record id="super_user" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">super_user</field>
            <field name="login">super_user</field>
            <field name="password">super_user</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('educationcenter.group_administrator'))]"/>
            <field name="partner_id" ref="educationcenter.partner_administrator"/>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>

And access rights are given to models as follows:
For better readability:



id
name
model_id:id
group_id:id
perm_read
perm_write
perm_create
perm_unlink




educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_admin
access_educationcenter_course_admin
model_educationcenter_course
educationcenter.group_admin
1
0
0
0


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_group_admin
access_educationcenter_course_group_admin
model_educationcenter_course_group
educationcenter.group_admin
1
0
0
0


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_payment_admin
access_educationcenter_payment_admin
model_educationcenter_payment
educationcenter.group_admin
1
1
0
0


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_student_admin
access_educationcenter_student_admin
model_educationcenter_student
educationcenter.group_admin
1
0
0
0


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_teacher_admin
access_educationcenter_teacher_admin
model_educationcenter_teacher
educationcenter.group_admin
1
1
0
0


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_administrator
access_educationcenter_course_administrator
model_educationcenter_course
educationcenter.group_administrator
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_group_administrator
access_educationcenter_course_group_administrator
model_educationcenter_course_group
educationcenter.group_administrator
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_payment_administrator
access_educationcenter_payment_administrator
model_educationcenter_payment
educationcenter.group_administrator
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_student_administrator
access_educationcenter_student_administrator
model_educationcenter_student
educationcenter.group_administrator
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_teacher_administrator
access_educationcenter_teacher_administrator
model_educationcenter_teacher
educationcenter.group_administrator
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_base_user
access_educationcenter_course_base_user
model_educationcenter_course
base.group_user
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_course_group_base_user
access_educationcenter_course_group_base_user
model_educationcenter_course_group
base.group_user
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_payment_base_user
access_educationcenter_payment_base_user
model_educationcenter_payment
base.group_user
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_student_base_user
access_educationcenter_student_base_user
model_educationcenter_student
base.group_user
1
1
1
1


educationcenter.access_educationcenter_teacher_base_user
access_educationcenter_teacher_base_user
model_educationcenter_teacher
base.group_user
1
1
1
1



I have some tree and form views for my models.
I can create a new db, activate the module and see all views as a user created via browser. But I cannot log in as users created from xmls above. I get following error:
2024-04-01 13:42:48,957 2460 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 9, model: res.users 
2024-04-01 13:42:48,958 2460 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 9, model: res.users 
2024-04-01 13:42:48,960 2460 WARNING odoo odoo.http: You are not allowed to access 'User' (res.users) records.
    
This operation is allowed for the following groups:
    - Administration/Access Rights
    - User types/Internal User
    - User types/Portal
    - User types/Public
    
Contact your administrator to request access if necessary.
    
Implicitly accessed through 'User' (res.users). 
2024-04-01 13:42:48,960 2460 INFO odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2024 13:42:48] "POST /web/login HTTP/1.1" 403 - 16 0.020 0.578

I can see that all groups and users are created in db, but I cannot log in as one of those users. What is the problem here?

I think there is an issue with the Odoo Controller.  See https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-implement-access-rights-to-a-controller-route-using-security-group-in-odoo13-230009
